# Java SubStrings and Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string

If I have a String variable containing a sentence, does anybody know how to extract the words from that sentence and store them in an array?

e.g. Take the String ("Hello World")

and store it like ["Hello","World"]

This is what I have been trying, but it doesn't work at all:

```
int newWord = 0;
String sentence;
String[] words;

for(count = 0; count < sentence.length(); count++)
    {
        words[newWord].charAt(count) = sentence.charAt(count);

        if(sentence.charAt(count) == ' ' )
        {
            newWord++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can do what Elliott said below or also `"Hello World".split(" ");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `String.split(String)` and a regular expression like `\\s+` (for one or more whitespace characters). Something like,

```
String[] words = "Hello World".split("\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
```

Output is (as requested)

```
[Hello, World]
```

Comment: @ElliotFrisch Thank you. Will this work if I am receiving input from the user and I cannot know the value of the String beforehand?

Comment: Yes. Replace `"Hello World"` with a `String` reference variable.